# Same region, different meshes

Tags: bugs, regions, finite-element-method

I'm playing around with `ToElementMesh` and I noticed the following behaviour that puzzles me. Consider the two regions

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`

Ω1 = 
  Polygon[{{-1/2, -1}, {-1/2, 1}, {1/2, 1}, {1/2, -1}}];
Ω2 = Rectangle[{-1/2, -1}, {1/2, 1}];
```

`RegionEqual[Ω1, Ω2]` returns `True`, but

```
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[Ω1, 
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation", MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05, 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.05];
mesh2 = ToElementMesh[Ω2, 
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation", MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05, 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.05];
Show[RegionPlot[Ω1], mesh1["Wireframe"]]
Show[RegionPlot[Ω2], mesh2["Wireframe"]]
```

yields two different meshes:

[image: mesh1]

[image: mesh2]

**Questions:**

1. Why this behaviour? From the documentation I couldn't find an explanation for this.
2. How can I control the mesh generation to get a uniform behaviour?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a shortcoming in `ToElementMesh`. I filed this as a bug, but it will take a bit of time to fix.

As a workaround you could use

```
mesh1 = 
  ToElementMesh[
    BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ω1, 
      MaxCellMeasure -> {"Edges" -> 0.01}], 
    "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation", MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05, 
    "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.01];
Show[RegionPlot[Ω1], mesh1["Wireframe"]]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to convey with `MaxCellMeasure -> {[![enter image description here][1]][1]"Edges" -> 0.01}],` Could you please replace that option clause with valid Mathematica code?

Comment: @m_goldberg, link to image went the wrong way. Fixed.