# Workaround for Mesh Generation Bugs?

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

I'm having trouble with the ToElementMesh and ImplicitRegion functions. There is a known bug that causes mesh variability ([bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148210/same-region-different-meshes)), but I couldn't find a workaround for the problem with the mesh below.

```
<< "NDSolve`FEM`"
Omega = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^1 <= 1 && Norm[(x + I y)^(1/2) - 0.4] >= 0.2, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];
ToElementMesh[Omega, AccuracyGoal -> 4, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]["Wireframe"]
RegionPlot[Omega]
```

The mesh clearly does not describe the region correctly (one of the boundaries should be the unit circle) and looking at RegionPlot it might be a problem with the ImplicitRegion definition. I have attached the output regions as images.

[image: meshregion]

[image: elementmesh]

Comment: It would be much easier to answer your question if you could post your actual code - not images of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same region, different meshes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148210/same-region-different-meshes)

Comment: Thanks user21, included the code now instead of images.

Comment: The new problem is caused by a typo, you've written `x^2 + y^1 <= 1` instead of `x^2 + y^2 <= 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @C. E. there is typo in the power of `y^1` - it should be `y^2`

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Omega = ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && 
    Norm[(x + I y)^(1/2) - 0.4] >= 0.2, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];
Show[ToElementMesh[Omega, AccuracyGoal -> 4, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001][
  "Wireframe"]
 , RegionPlot[Omega]]
```

[image]

Comment: Whoops, thanks! I'm still having a bug, which is that when I define a mesh through an expression using complex coordinates, I compute the accuracy to be less than 70% in some cases. 

It's concerning to me that in the "ToBoundaryMesh" documentation under "Possible Issues" there is the statement "Sometime boundary features may not be resolved well:" Do people know of any workarounds to this issue other than the one suggested in the documentation?

Comment: @user49533, if you post (as a new question) the example you have issue with I can have a look.

Comment: I just posted an example that's closer to my issue [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148444/how-to-increase-boundary-mesh-quality)